# Is there an alternate way to conditionally increment array values without using if statements? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

If have an array,

```
int amounts[26] = { 0, 0, 0, ...};
```

and I want each digit of the array to represent the amount of a different string, such that `amounts[0] = amount;` of `'a'`'s that are found within a given string, is there anyway to increment each value without using if statements?

Psuedocode example:

```
int amounts[26] = { 0, 0, 0, ...}; 
string word = "blahblah";
loop here to check and increment amounts[0] based on amount of 'a's in string
repeat loop for each letter in word.`
```

At the end of the loop, based on the string word, amounts should be as follows:

```
amounts[0] = 2 ('a')
amounts[1] = 2  ('b')
amounts[2] = 0  ('c')
// etc
```

Comment: Do you mean without if statements in specific, or without branching in general?

Comment: If I understand, something like `++amounts[word[i] - 'a'];`?

Comment: Are you okay limiting yourself to specific character sets or are you looking for a completely generic/portable solution?

Answer (score 5):

Given your example, assuming the entire string is lowercase and valid characters, there's a fairly simply solution (that is to say, you handle the validation)

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    amounts[word[i]-'a']++; // you can also do a pre-increment if you want
}
```

Comment: Do not that this is not portable.  One of the character sets  C++ requires support for ([EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) does not map `a - z` to a contiguous range.

Comment: Just to add, since nobody's mentioned it yet, this isn't portable.

Comment: Agreeing on the EBCDIC issue - although most likely not of much relevance. More critical: What if we have both upper and lower case letters or non-alphabetical characters in the string?

Comment: @Aconcagua if you read the first part of the answer "assuming the entire string is lowercase and valid characters, there's a fairly simply solution (that is to say, you handle the validation)"

Comment: But if you wanted a more general (and I'd argue better) answer, one solution would be to make a mapping all desired characters to the appropriate indexes, and if the character isn't in the mapping it's an invalid char and can be handled however you want

Answer (score 1):

What you want:

```
const char char_offset = 'a';
const int num_chars = 26;
std::vector<int> amounts(num_chars, 0);
std::string word = "blahblah";

for (auto c : word) {
  int i = c - char_offset;
  // this if statement is only for range checking.
  // you can remove it if you are sure about the data range.
  if (i >= 0 && i < num_chars) { 
    ++amounts[i];
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < (int)amounts.size(); ++i) {
  std::cout << (char)(char_offset + i) << ": " << amounts[i] << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
Output
a: 2
b: 2
c: 0
d: 0
e: 0
f: 0
g: 0
h: 2
i: 0
j: 0
k: 0
l: 2
m: 0
n: 0
...
```

Comment: _"without using if statements"_

Comment: This is only for range checking. You can surely skip it if you don't care it.

Comment: I don't really see why this is worthy of a downvote, some of it's a bit verbose but...?

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::unordered_map< std::string, int >](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Note that std::unordered_map< char, int > would be more efficient if only a single character is required. std::string allows counting complex strings (e.g. map["substring"]++ )

Maps can be accessed using bracket notation ( e.g. map[index] ), and thus can effectively remove the need for if statements.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map< std::string, int > map = {  {"a",0} };
    map["a"] += 1;
    std::cout << map["a"];
}
```

Comment: Seems like `std::unordered_map< char, int >` would be enough. And there's no need to initialize the map. `operator[]` will insert a zero element if the key isn't in use yet.

Comment: Why not `std::unordered_map< char, int >`?  Paying for a `std::string` when you only need a single character is a bit excessive.

Comment: Also this can be more generic if you allow the user to specify the alphabet as a `std::string`, and then populate the map using a loop, i.e. `std::string alpha = "abcdef..."`, then write a loop to populate the map starting from `{a, 0}`.

Comment: OP said he wanted to "to represent the amount of a different string," thus the use of std::string. I may have taken it too literally. Yes, char would be more efficient, but this is more flexible. 

I only initialized to make it easier to visualize how the values are held.

Answer (score 1):

The following has quite some chances of being one of the fastest in matters of counting:

```
std::array<unsigned int, (1U << CHAR_BIT)> counts({ });
for(auto c : word)
    counts[c]++;
```

Getting individual values is quite efficient:

```
 std::cout << "a: " << counts['a'] << std::endl
```

Iterating over the letters - well, will require a little trick:

```
 for(char const* c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; *c; ++c)
     // case-insensitive:
     std::cout << *c << ": " << counts[*c] + counts[toupper(*c)] << std::endl;
```

Sure, you are wasting a bit of memory - which might cost you the performance gained again: If the array does not fit into the cache any more...

Comment: @Aconcagua - the minimum value of `CHAR_BIT` allowed is `8`.   (The C++ standards refer to the C standards for the specification of macros in `<climits>` and `<limits.h>`, and the C standards set a lower bound of `8`).

Comment: Right; I misunderstood your answer. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

A general and portable solution would be

```
const std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (int i = 0; alphabet[i]; ++i)
      amounts[i] = std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), alphabet[i]);
```

If you can assume the set of lowercase letters is a contiguous range, this can be simplified to

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
    amounts[c - 'a'] = std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), c);
```

No (overt) `if` in the above.   Of course, there is nothing preventing `std::count()` being implemented using one.